# Adding a value to an empty array in python

Tags: javascript, python, arrays

how would I go about initiating a 'randomDirection' variable to hold a random value from the directions array, and set the lastDirection variable to an empty array in python?

Here is the code in JavaScript, how can I convert it into Python?

```
let lastDirection = [], randomDirection;
```

Comment: `random.choice`

Comment: In Python `[]` creates a list, not an array.

Comment: Your JavaScript code is not *"initiating a randomDirection variable to hold a random value from the directions array"*. Nor does it do what you have in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note that `[]` in Python creates a `list`, and not an array.)

Your question's title seems to be asking a different question than your question's body, so I'll answer both.
To append an element `elem` to a list `l` in Python, you could do any of the following (I recommend looking into all three for the educational value):

```
l += [a]
l.append(a)
l.extend([a])
```

There are differences between those but each of those would result in `l` having `a` added as its last element.

To choose a random element from a list called `directions` and put it in lastDirection, you could use random.choice (remember to `import random` for this):

```
lastDirection = random.choice(directions)
```

If you want lastDirection to be an array and to just append directions to it as you go, then you could initialize it like so:

```
lastDirection = []
```

And then append elements to it using one of the methods noted above.

Comment: Perfect this worked thank you! and does math.random work with python or do I have to use the random module?

Comment: @JedidiahBlitz You're welcome and I'm happy I could help :) Python's `math` module has no `random` as far as I know, but you could generate a random floating point number in [0.0, 1.0) using `random.random()`, or random integers in [a,b] using `random.randint(a, b)`. Another interesting option is `numpy.random.choice`, which enables you to provide probabilities for the various options.

Comment: (So the one that's like JavaScript's `math.random` is `random.random`; but it's still in the `random` module.) Is there a particular reason you consider avoiding using the `random` module?

Comment: less modules having to be imported XD just me being lazy

Comment: @JedidiahBlitz ah.  I'm afraid any alternative method I can think of requires a lot more work than just importing `random` (like "manually generating" random bits using a clock drift effect).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a directions array then we use the random module to help us choose a random direction in directions. Also, an empty list can be set by initializing a variable to `[]`.

```py
import random

directions = ['N', 'S', 'W', 'E']
random_direction = random.choice(directions)
last_direction = []
```

Comment: Yes so I have a directions array that looks like this: directions = [[-1, 0], [1, 0], [0, -1], [0, 1]] and a do while loop after that adds value to the randomDirection variable based on certain circumstances.

Comment: And does math.random() work with python?

Answer (score 0):

In python you dont need to put `let`, `var`, or `const`. And you dont need to put `;` at the end of every line of code you write:

```
lastDirection = ([]), randomDirection
```